# no such file or directory cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I just import a sample cocos2dx project when build it appear no such file or directory c/c++ problem. Any idea?

my android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/CCParallaxNodeExtras.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes                   

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

Comment: You should include the error message in your question, _exactly_ as it was given to you.

Comment: the error msg is this "no such file or directory c/c++ problem"

Comment: is your build_native.sh the default one or have you modified it?